# WxPython button to run script

Tags: python, user-interface, button, wxpython

I've created a custom bitmap button 
using the code

```
PlayButton=wx.Bitmap('play.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
self.PlayButton=wx.BitmapButton(self.bitmap, -1, PlayButton, pos=(190,300))
self.PlayButton.Bind=(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.playGame)
```

Just wondering when it comes to defining my function playGame, how I could run an external python file 'game.py' in the same directory when it's clicked

Answer (score 1):

You can import your script as module.

```
import game

...

def playGame(self):
    game.start()
```

Comment: in this case you have to organize your script like a module.
Please, share the error

Comment: When you mean to organize like a module, do I still have my imports on that script at the top and then one big function?